# jquery toggle bottom left to top right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle

i have got this script all works fine but i was wonder if its possible to toggle bottom left to top right

```
    $("a#slick-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#slickbox").animate({width: "toggle", 
                height: "toggle"}, 1000);
});
```

thank Gareth

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/ has an example of movement. Top right can be set via css as `top: 0px; right: 0px;` so it would be something like:

```
.animate({
  top: 0,
  right: 0,
  height: 'toggle'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position as relative then also animate the `left` property, like this:

```
$("a#slick-toggle").click(function() {
  var sb = $("#slickbox").stop(true, true), w = sb.is(":visible") ? sb.width():0;
  sb.animate({width: "toggle", height: "toggle", left: w}, 1000);
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qCq9d/), what this does is grab the [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) of the element and moves it that far to the left in the animation, giving the effect of it collapsing to the right, rather than the left.  The [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) portion is to prevent animation queue-up and that [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is the appropriate value when going to access it (not a mid-animation width).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you ***can*** `float` your `#slickbox` to `right`!

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#slick-toggle").click(function() {
    $("#slickbox").animate({width: "toggle",
                height: "toggle"}, 1000);
    return false;
  });
});
```

**HTML**
Please note : `float: right`

```
<a href="#" id="slick-toggle">Clicked</a><br />
<div style="width: 25px; float: left;">
 <div id="slickbox" style="float: right;">Testt</div>
</div>
```

[See Demo](http://jsbin.com/erele3/)